# Accessing Openstack Swift deployment on EC2 VM remotely

Tags: amazon-ec2, openstack, openstack-swift

So, i have deployed Swift Object Storage on an EC2 VM. I am able to access the objects using curl/python client for swift from the same VM.

However, I am not sure how to access the same remotely using the public URL for my swift deployment.

On browsing, I came across swift3 (https://github.com/openstack/swift3), but I am not sure how to configure this and whether this is even applicable in my case (As I am not using S3 but only using EC2).

Comment: Have you tried accessing it remotely with the curl/python client for swift at your public URL?

Comment: Do I need to setup passwordless ssh first ? I don't see a way of incorporating AWS credentials in the curl command

Comment: You don't need AWS credentials to access a public URL. Did you enable access from the outside (public) for that EC2 VM for the port the swift API proxy is exposed on (usually the default HTTPS port 443) in AWS?